# add multiple rows/columns in a sparse matrix scipy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a scipy sparse matrix, where I need to add multiple rows (in blocks), say 1:30, then 45:50, etc. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: By 'add multiple rows' do you mean 'insert between these two rows' or 'write to these rows'?

Comment: No, I want a new vector which will be the result of addition of multiple row vectors

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't `sum` do the job? try:

```
a = np.array([[1,1],
              [2,2],
              [3,3]])
>>> a[1:3]
array([[2, 2],
       [3, 3]])

>>> sum(a[1:3])
10
```

Edit: if you are looking to sum 'vertically'

```
>>> sum( a, axis=0 )
array([6, 6])
```

Comment: it's a sparse matrix, hence numpy.sum(a[1:3]) raises an Indexerror.

Comment: which type of sparse matrix are you using? I tried with csr but haven't encountered indexerror... although have to do it in the form of a[0:2].sum(axis=0)

Comment: I realize that the software behavior may have changed quite a bit since this question was asked, but with python 3.6.7, numpy 1.15.4, scipy 0.19.1 the proposed solution `np.sum(matrix[firstRow:lastRow])` works fine with csr matrices.